# Getting SQL Server Scalar-Valued function result from a DataSet

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I've a DataSet with a TableAdapter mapping to a Scalar-valued function in SQL Server.

How I can get the result returned by the SQL Server's function?

I've tried using

```
fnGetWorkersCountTableAdapter wc = new fnGetWorkersCountTableAdapter();
wc.Fill(myDataSet1);
```

in the same way I do when I wanna get the rows returned by a stored procedure but in the case of the function the Fill method returns 0.

Why is this happening?

Comment: is that work for you ?? aslo check answer of the link ..